# Changing the program flow when running under a debugger

Tags: .net, debugging, in-memory, cracking

Is there any way of detecting that a debugger is running in memory?

and here comes the on Form Load pseudocode.

```
if debugger.IsRunning then
Application.exit
end if
```

**Edit:** The original title was "Detecting an in memory debugger"

Comment: Most debuggers can be attached to a process at runtime. In that case checking for debugger on statrup won't help much.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Try the following

```
if ( System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached ) {
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Two things to keep in mind before using this to close an application running in the debugger:

1. I've used a debugger to pull a crash trace from a commercial .NET application and send it to the company where it was subsequently fixed with a thank you for making it easy and
2. That check can be *trivially* defeated.

Now, to be of more use, here's how to use this detection to keep [func eval](http://blogs.msdn.com/jmstall/archive/2005/11/15/funceval-rules.aspx) in the debugger from changing your program state if you have a cache a lazily evaluated property for performance reasons.

```
private object _calculatedProperty;

public object SomeCalculatedProperty
{
    get
    {
        if (_calculatedProperty == null)
        {
            object property = /*calculate property*/;
            if (System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached)
                return property;

            _calculatedProperty = property;
        }

        return _calculatedProperty;
    }
}
```

I've also used this variant at times to ensure my debugger step-through doesn't skip the evaluation:

```
private object _calculatedProperty;

public object SomeCalculatedProperty
{
    get
    {
        bool debuggerAttached = System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached;

        if (_calculatedProperty == null || debuggerAttached)
        {
            object property = /*calculate property*/;
            if (debuggerAttached)
                return property;

            _calculatedProperty = property;
        }

        return _calculatedProperty;
    }
}
```

Comment: That's a cool idea - but it changes the flow of your program when running under a debugger, so you're no longer debugging the code that you use in release. IMHO it would be better in most cases to provide a non-cached variant of the property (inside #if DEBUG so it's not built into releases) that you can use in the debugger to examine the value, leaving the "real" property working the same way in both debug & release builds.

Comment: @Jason: yes and no. In this case, all methods called to evaluate the property are pure (no side effects regardless of when called), so I was actually ensuring that this held for properties as well from the application's perspective.

Comment: Do you think this approach is valid if you want to create a library that only works on debug mode from visual studio? I want to create a library that is free to test from visual studio but cannot be included in an application built on release mode